# Github graph doesn't show commits created before creating an account

Tags: git, github

I was using my e-mail address  to create commits on public github repositories, but I didn't have any github account. After some time I created my account and added my e-mail address. It seems to be OK however Github graph shows only commits which I produced after creating my account on Github. Those commits which were created before joining to Github are not present on the graph.

Is there any solution to solve this issue and show on graph commits created before joining to github?

Comment: I don't think so. It doesn't make sense to track only commits of for an account that didn't exist before. When you create a commit and push it to a tracking branch (let's say master), at that point GH will list your contribution. Check to what type of branches you have been contributing, but I doubt GH is tracking your contributions before you had an account.